# angular.js md-chips email validation and change invalid email background color

Tags: angularjs

How to create an email validation for md-chips? My expression below is not working, since, the ng-keypress directive is called whenever I type something.

1. I need attached image type validation.
2. How to set onload email data in mat-chip.
3. How to set not-valid email background color.
4. How to validate email.

```
HTML

<div ng-controller="CustomSeparatorCtrl as ctrl" layout="column" ng-cloak>
  <md-content class="md-padding" layout="column">

    <h2 class="md-title">
      Use <code>md-separator-keys</code> to customize the key codes which trigger chip creation.
    </h2>
    <md-subheader id="commaSeparatorKeyDescription">
      You can use either the Enter or Comma keys to trigger chip creation.
    </md-subheader>
    <md-chips
      ng-model="ctrl.tags" input-aria-label="Tags"
      md-separator-keys="ctrl.keys"
      placeholder="Ex. angularjs-material"
      secondary-placeholder="Add another tag"
      input-aria-describedby="commaSeparatorKeyDescription">
    </md-chips>
    <br/>

    <h2 class="md-title">Add custom separator key codes such as semicolon for e-mails.</h2>
    <md-subheader id="customSeparatorKeyDescription">
      You can use the Semicolon, Enter, or Comma keys to trigger chip creation.
    </md-subheader>
    <md-chips
      ng-model="ctrl.contacts" input-aria-label="Emails"
      md-separator-keys="ctrl.customKeys" placeholder="Ex. myemail@example.com"
      secondary-placeholder="Add another email address"
      input-aria-describedby="customSeparatorKeyDescription">
    </md-chips>

  </md-content>
</div>
```

```
js

(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular
      .module('chipsCustomSeparatorDemo', ['ngMaterial'])
      .controller('CustomSeparatorCtrl', DemoCtrl);

  function DemoCtrl ($mdConstant) {
    // Use common key codes found in $mdConstant.KEY_CODE...
    this.keys = [$mdConstant.KEY_CODE.ENTER, $mdConstant.KEY_CODE.COMMA];
    this.tags = [];

    // Any key code can be used to create a custom separator
    var semicolon = 186;
    this.customKeys = [$mdConstant.KEY_CODE.ENTER, $mdConstant.KEY_CODE.COMMA, semicolon];
    this.contacts = ['test@example.com'];
  }
})();
```

[image]